# number of "some"

Tags: numbers

> “What are **some** of the good releases this summer?”
>   “I think **one** of the best books is a book called ‘Into Thin Air’ by John Krakauer. “
>   (COCA)

‘*Some*’ seems to be plural, for there is ‘*are*.’ While the answerer says a single pronoun, *one*. Does ‘*some*’ have the meaning of ‘*more than or equal to one*’? Or does the answerer ignores the question’s number and initiate his own words?

Comment: Your second assumption seems correct. The responder ignores the request for more than one book, answering with only a single book.

Comment: It *is* a [cooperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) response, though.

Comment: Think of it this way:  The asker may be asking a group of students this question and while each student might supply a single answer, the group may collectively provide several (or *some*) answers.   Also, you should read the answer above with some emphasis on *one* which makes it clear the answerer understand you asked for *some* and what they are providing is just one of the potential items in the list.

Comment: If the answerer _has_ to adjust to the number in the question, he would be unable to answer if the answer involves a single item. (Or vice versa: Which one of you did this? We did it together!) There is absolutely no reason why someone would feel he should not give a useful answer just because of some grammatical rule - and there _is_ not even such a rule!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take another example:

> What are some of the good movies getting released in coming 2 months?

Of course, the asker is interested in *more than one* movies as you guessed it correctly by the word *are*.

> [Not sure about other movies but..] *one of the good movies* I think coming is Expendables.

The answerer simply tells his opinion that *one of the...* is what he thinks is a good-watch.

So to answer, *some* here has *more than one* meaning which the answerer does not seem to ignore by giving his/er humble opinion.